# SSRS Conditional Formatting Switch or IIF

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, switch-statement, iif-function

I currently have the following 2008 SSRS Report and I want to conditionally format background of the columns based on some logic.

I have three columns and two of which I would like to change the background color.
Columns "Current Risk Level", "Trend", "Tolerance". Each contains rows of either Low, Moderate, Medium, High, Very High

For column "Current Risk Level" I would like Low="Green",Moderate="Blue",Medium="Yellow",High="Orange",Very High="Red"

For column "Tolerance" I would like
Low="Red",Moderate="Orange",Medium="Yellow",High="Blue",Very High="Green"

I don't know how to set up a SWITCH or IIF function to accomplish this.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To dynamically change the color of a text box goto properties, goto font/Color and set the following expression

```
=SWITCH(Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Low", "Green",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Moderate", "Blue",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Medium", "Yellow",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "High", "Orange",
Fields!CurrentRiskLevel.Value = "Very High", "Red"
)
```

Same way for tolerance

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Tolerance.Value = "Low", "Red",
Fields!Tolerance.Value = "Moderate", "Orange",
Fields!Tolerance.Value = "Medium", "Yellow",
Fields!Tolerance.Value = "High", "Blue",
Fields!Tolerance.Value = "Very High", "Green")
```

Comment: It worked great! Thank you so much. I spent forever trying to get this to work.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Please consider marking an answer as accepted if it solved your issue. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: What if I have 6 rows in my table and I need to change cell colors only for row #3, not for the whole table. How can I do that?
Something like =
`SWITCH 
    ( IIF(Fields!Underwriter.Value="Brown, Debra"  THEN  
  Fields!PoliciesBound.Value = 0, "Tomato",
        Fields!PoliciesBound.Value >=1  and Fields!PoliciesBound.Value <= 5 , "Yellow", 
  Fields!PoliciesBound.Value >=6  and Fields!PoliciesBound.Value <= 10 , "Gold", 
        Fields!PoliciesBound.Value >= 11 and Fields!PoliciesBound.Value <= 16,"#bdff30",
  )`

Comment: @Oleg  iif(RowNumber(Nothing) = 3 , SWITCH() , "White")