# IIF function in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am totally new in SSRS and even in C# programming. I am making a report card program and in the final output which is the report card itself, I need to  make a condition where:

Letter Grade
94-100 = A
89-93 = A-
and so on.

Grade Point
94-100 = 4.00
89-93 = 3.75
and so on.

Can anybody help me on this? I am using SSRS for the final output of the report card. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Conditional Formatting Switch or IIF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538222/ssrs-conditional-formatting-switch-or-iif)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SWITCH` instead of `IIF` in following:

**Letter Grade**:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Col.Value > 94 AND Fields!Col.Value < 100, "A",
        Fields!Col.Value > 89 AND Fields!Col.Value < 93, "A-",
        and so on
        )
```

**Grade Point**:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!Col.Value > 94 AND Fields!Col.Value < 100, "4.00",
        and so on
        )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I've been trying to figure out this for a week and now...Merry Christmas to you and Happy New Year. I wish you all the best for the next year. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: @HoldOn glad to help you, do not forget to accept It as correct answer. To do that you can Mark `V` in top-left corner of an answer.