# SSRS SWITCH Syntax not working

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, ssrs-2008-r2, iif-function

I have a columns in my dataset that will be returning several different values.  In an attempt to  to use grouping in the report I am trying to clean up the data.  After reading several posts I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538222/ssrs-conditional-formatting-switch-or-iif) that seemed to be very close to what I needed.

I set up my expressions like this

```
=SWITCH(
Left(Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value,3)="ACE","ACE WRECKER",
Left(Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value,3)="CAR","CAR STORE",
Left(Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value,7)="THE CAR","CAR STORE",
Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value
```

)

The expression does not throw an error when I preview it, but all the columns show "error"  Can anyone please show me where I am going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: The part `,Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value` looks like unneeded code. Try it without that.

Comment: thanks for the quick response R.Richards.  I removed that line and it now runs, but is only showing the three I have put in the switch statement.  I though the line I removed would show any records I did not catch in the SWITCH

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work like that. I wish it did. Having a default when nothing else matches would be a nice feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Switch` statement requires pairs of arguments. You can't just have the last value by itself as an `Else` condition. Try this:

```
=SWITCH(
Left(Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value,3)="ACE","ACE WRECKER",
Left(Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value,3)="CAR","CAR STORE",
Left(Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value,7)="THE CAR","CAR STORE",
True, Fields!T6_TOW_BY.Value
)
```