# multiple conditional formatting in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Hi i have 2 conditions for a column in an SSRS report.

> ```
> if Expirationdate <= Begdate  then red 
> if Begdate <Expirationdate<Enddate then orange
> else white.
> ```

This is what i have currently.

```
=iif((Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value <= Parameters!BEGDATE.Value), "Red"
,iif((Fields!LICENSENUM.Value<Parameters!BEGDATE.Value) and (Fields!LICENSENUM.Value>Parameters!ENDDATE.Value)) , "Orange","White")
```

is there something i am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you explain what is happening that is Wrong? You haven't expressed what the problem is

Comment: @ChanceFinley Sorry with my current FX my report is not building . I get an overload resolution failed because no accesible 'iif' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: I would recommend using switch instead of nested IIF. The ELSE can be emulated by setting the last expression to always true. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538222/ssrs-conditional-formatting-switch-or-iif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have too many IIFs and brackets.

Try this:

```
=iif(Fields!EXPIRATIONDATE.Value <= Parameters!BEGDATE.Value, "Red", iif(Fields!LICENSENUM.Value < Parameters!BEGDATE.Value and Fields!LICENSENUM.Value > Parameters!ENDDATE.Value , "Orange", "White"))
```

Comment: Thank you! it looks like the parentheses matter as well.  working great!