# Group by Switch or IIF - RDLC report (Age Ranges of Customers)

Tags: c#, reporting-services, switch-statement, ssrs-grouping

As a precursor to this i read:
[SSRS Conditional Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18538222/ssrs-conditional-formatting-switch-or-iif), however I have tried and I'm just not getting anywhere.

I originally tried supplying the data in the table query using a switch statement, which failed, so i have now brought all the data into a table, and now i just want to run a switch statement for Age Ranges and Count the age ranges!

Data is:
[Customerid] = int32
[age] = int32

I have created a table in my report:

[image]

I have tried:
iif statement:

```
=iif(Fields!Age.Value < 18,"< 18", 
iif(Fields!Age.Value <30, "18-30", 
iif(Fields!Age.Value < 45, "30-45", ">45")))
```

[image]
This is obviously not working, as ages 16 arent appearing in the <18 section

I have also tried this with a switch(expression,string) expression and not having any luck there either!?

Ideas?

Comment: Your expression is correct, you can check it by adding a column next to age to check the expression. I think that maybe there is something wrong with your group values

Comment: Thanks @niktrs.  So i have one group which is the iif statement, and then the subgroup under that is just the default details group..
The IIF statemnet should be the group expression shouldnt it? Thats what i have currently

Comment: Yes the expression should be set both as group expression and group value. What about the column named group3? Is it part of the detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group expression should be

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!Age.Value <18, "< 18",
Fields!Age.Value <30, "18-29",
Fields!Age.Value <45, "30-45",
True, ">45"
)
```

Report design something like ...

[image]

The expression in column 1 is also the same as the group expression.

This gives you this as output (based on your sample data)
[image]

You'll need to probably do something with the group order but I'm in a rush !

Comment: omg you have made my week.

So i believe what i was doing wrong in my switch expression was
using AND (eg value < 30 and value > 18) etc.

I still dont know why my IIF statement didnt work, but either way, THANKS YOU.
Ill look into group ordering now :) OMG im so happy

Comment: The group order expression can probably just use the same `SWITCH` expression but replace you age bands with numbers (swap "<18" for a 0 "18-29" for a 1 etc and that should (untested) do the job

Comment: yup did that a few mins ago :) Thanks again